# SSRS Report: How to start report on row 1, and how to show grid lines?

Tags: sql-server, excel, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

Our SSRS Report uses Generic table style (any style I select has the same issue).

1. The report header starts on row 2 of the table, and the data after that. How can I make the report header starts on row 1 ?
2. The report has no grid lines after the end of my data. Say I have data until row 8, the grid lines only show until row 8.
   How can I show grid lines for all rows, even ones after the last row with data ? In Design mode, I had selected all cells and set BorderStyle = Solid and BorderColor = Black

Here is a screenshot:

[image]

Comment: For item number 2, How far should the grid lines go?  How will the report know when to stop?  It is putting in the lines for the data in the report.

Comment: Hi,
Since the user is viewing the report in Excel, the user wants grid lines on every row, just like there is grid lines on every rows in Excel

Answer (score 0):

The problem with item number 2 is the rows could potentially go up the max limit of rows allowed in Excel, which would create a much larger report than is necessary.  Explain to the user you don't need more grid lines then there is data for.

For item number 1, is that in SSRS or Excel?  You should be able to remove the header level row from the object so your data begins with no header columns.

Answer (score 0):

For issue #1 You need to ensure that the graph/chart/table you are trying to display is oriented at (0 inch, length(previous item) inch) i.e. make sure you place it directly under the previous item. Also, include a page break after the previous item. If this is the only item in your report just orient it @ (0 inch,0 inch) you can control this in the location tab in the properties window.
For issue #2. Ensure there is a page break after